# Should I make a mini-greenhouse for my temperature-sensitive bonsai?

Tags: bonsai, greenhouse, temperature

I have a **5 years old Fukien Tea**, which just arrived in home. I live in the south of Spain, and my city has strong temperature changes. The temperature goes aprox. like this:

- **Spring:** 20 - 25 º Celsius / Fahrenheit 68 - 77 º
- **Summer:** 35 - 40 º C /       F 95 - 104 º
- **Autumn:** 15 - 25 º C /       F 59 - 77 º
- **Winter:** 1 - 12 º C /        F 32 - 54 º

I keep the bonsai in my desktop, which is in front of a big window with sunlight, but I read Fukien Tea should also go out. Apparently the **perfect temperature for it is 20 º C/ F 68 º**. I'm worried about **summer and winter** for this little guy, I thought to get a *mini-greenhouse* for keep it humid and temperature-shock free in winter.

**Do you think is it a good idea or the bonsai could be harm? What could I do in summer?**

RPI/Arduino homemade devices are possible options, do you guys tried anything?

**Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 3):

Fukien Tea is a tropical plant and is one of the few species that can be successfully grown indoor as a bonsai. However, keep in mind indoor bonsai is much more difficult than growing outdoor bonsai.

I do bonsai for many years now (mostly outdoor species), and have tried some indoor trees as well. I never tried Fukien Tea, but have tried *Podocarpus* and *Ficus benjamina*. The *Podocarpus* died, and altought the *Ficus* is still alive it is not as good in shape as my outdoor bonsai. I don't want to discourage you of course, but please be aware of the difficulty.

As you already mentioned, temperature is an important factor. I think in Spain the bonsai will do good outside during summertime. Maybe keep it in the shade when really high temperature occur. For winter it needs to be inside, and will encounter two main problems. First light, it is a tropical plant that gets full light whole year thru in normal habitat. But here in Europe the light intensity and day length will be less. Second problem, and this is more important is moist levels. Since it is a tropical plant it needs moist soil. In wintertime, when the heater is on, the air can be dry, and the plant and soil will evaporate faster. I don't think you'll need a mini-green house to regulate moist levels, but putting the pot on something like a wet tray of gravel might be the best solution. Here is some more info about [Fukien Tea bonsai](https://www.bonsaiempire.com/tree-species/carmona) maintenance.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your recommendations. First thing I'll do is to set the wet tray and monitor it closely.